# Rails include returns filtered relations instead of all relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm using an `includes` instead of a `join` because it runs faster but the statement is returning an association that doesn't include all of the data I'm looking for. It returns all of the left data, but only the right data that matches the query. Hopefully the examples below help clarify the problem and what I'm trying to achieve.

The `join` does seem to do what I'm after from a data and rails association perspective but executes a ton of queries and is much slower.

### Setup and examples

```
class Species < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :species_types, foreign_key: 'species_id', primary_key: "id"

end

class SpeciesTypes < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :species, :foreign_key => "id", :primary_key => "species_id"

end

create_table "species", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "id"
    t.string "identifier"
end

create_table "species_types", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "species_id"
    t.bigint "type_id"
    t.string "name"
end
```

Table data to help visualize the queries below

#### Species

| id | identifier |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | furry |
| 2 | sleek |
| 3 | hairy |
| 4 | shiny |
| 5 | reflective |
| 6 | rough |
| 7 | rubbery |

#### SpeciesTypes

| species_id | type_id | identifier |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | hairy |
| 1 | 2 | metalic |
| 2 | 3 | skin |
| 3 | 1 | hairy |
| 4 | 2 | metalic |
| 4 | 3 | skin |
| 5 | 3 | skin |
| 5 | 3 | skin |
| 6 | 2 | metalic |
| 7 | 2 | metalic |

I know the `SpeciesTypes.type_id`, and I'm looking to get all `Species` that have that type, including all of their SpeciesTypes.

#### Using `includes`

```
`species = Species.includes(:species_types).where(:species_types => {:type_id => 1})`
```

This does return all Species with a matching SpeciesType. However, instead of returning all Species with all SpeciesType it return all Species with only the SpeciesType that match the `:type_id` parameter. So, in this case you cannot reference all SpeciesTypes from the Species object (`species[0].species_types`). Does not return what was expected, although it makes sense why it does limit to the matched type_id.

###### Response from above query for Species

```
irb()$ species = Species.includes(:species_types).where(:species_types => {:type_id => 1})
irb()$ species[0].species_types

[#<SpeciesTypes:0x0000ffff9ad73490                       
 species_id: 1,
 type_id: 1,
 identifier: hairy>]
```

###### I'm looking for this:

```
irb()$ species = Species.includes(:species_types).where(:species_types => {:type_id => 1})
irb()$ species[0].species_types

[#<SpeciesTypes:0x0000ffff9ad73490                       
 species_id: 1,
 type_id: 1,
 identifier: hairy>,
 <SpeciesTypes:0x0000ffff9ad73490                       
 species_id: 1,
 type_id: 2,
 identifier: metalic>,
 ]
```

#### Using `joins`

This is returning what I'm after (using `join` instead of `includes`) however the query is much much slower. I think I'm missing something obvious (or not obvious but fundamental)

```
species = Species.joins(:species_types).where(:species_types => {:type_id => 3})
```

The above returns the values that I expect but *is* a much slower query.

Can the `includes` query be updated to return all Species with all types that match the known `:type_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While its pretty natural to think that `Species.includes(:species_types).where(:species_types => {:type_id => 3})` would load all the species and just eager load the species_types that match the where clause thats not how ActiveRecord and SQL actually works.

What this generates in terms of a query something like:

```
SELECT species.name AS t0_c1, species_types.id AS t1_c1 ...
LEFT OUTER JOIN species_types, t1
  ON species_types.specie_id = species.id
WHERE species_types.type_id = ?
```

When you use `includes` and reference the other table it delegates to `.eager_load` which loads both tables in a single database query.

The where clause here applies to the entire query and not just the joined assocation. Remember that this query returns a row for every `species_types` row (with duplicate data for the species table).

If you wanted to load just the records that match the condition you would need to put the restriction into the JOIN clause:

```
SELECT species.name AS t0_c1, ...
LEFT OUTER JOIN species_types, t1
  ON species_types.specie_id = species.id AND species_types.type_id = ?
```

Unfortunately ActiveRecord associations do not provide a way to do that.

The easiest solution to the problem is most likely to just query from the other end:

```
Type.find(1)
    .specie_types.where(specie: specie)
```

### `.joins` is not the answer

You can't just replace `includes` with `joins` as they do very things.

`joins` just adds an `INNER LEFT JOIN` to the query but doesn't actually select any columns from the joined table. Its used to filter the assocation based on the joined table or to select aggregates. Not to prevent N+1 queries.

In this case it's most likely not the first query itself thats slower - rather you're creating a N+1 query when you iterate through `specie_types` as the assocation is not eager loaded / preloaded.

`includes` does an `OUTER LEFT JOIN` and will load the assocatiated records either in one or two queries depending on how its used.

Comment: Thanks a ton, max. I appreciate the time, and it confirms what I was thinking re. multiple scans. I'll give this a bit to sink in and try your suggestion of starting at the other end.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't really something that ActiveRecord handles well. With assocations and eager loading you get pretty much all or nothing and if you just want a subset of an assocation you have to get creative.

Comment: Thanks again - you're a miracle worker :D. While I wasn't able to get this down to a single query, I was able to have it generate a few very targeted queries that create the associations with the data I need, and eager loads (probably not using that term correctly) the data into the associations that I'm using when rendering the ui.

I ended up with something like `BaseType.find(params[:type]).species.includes(species_types: [:type_names, :base_type])`

This required a minor enhancement to defined pk and fk values in the models, but works beautifully.

Comment: Given that, you've helped me understand a little more what's happening under the hood, and pushed me to understand the rails models a bit more, as well as learn from the sql output in the rails server logs. Thanks.